# How to uppercase a string in the Inno Setup Preprocessor?

Tags: inno-setup

I found the [`LowerCase` preprocessor function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=lowercase), but I did not see an `UpperCase` preprocesor function.  There is a Pascal Script [`Uppercase`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_uppercase) and [`Lowercase`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_lowercase).

Ok, there's not an uppercase in the preprocessor.  How should we uppercase something in the preprocessor?

Answer (score 3):

The [`UpperCase` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=uppercase) was added in only in Inno Setup 6.0.4.

---

In older versions of Inno Setup, you can define your own.

If ascii `a-z` are enough for you, this will do:

```
#define UpperCase(str S) \
    S = StringChange(S, 'a', 'A'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'b', 'B'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'c', 'C'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'd', 'D'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'e', 'E'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'f', 'F'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'g', 'G'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'h', 'H'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'i', 'I'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'j', 'J'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'k', 'K'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'l', 'L'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'm', 'M'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'n', 'N'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'o', 'O'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'p', 'P'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'q', 'Q'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'r', 'R'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 's', 'S'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 't', 'T'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'u', 'U'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'v', 'V'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'w', 'W'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'x', 'X'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'y', 'Y'), \
    S = StringChange(S, 'z', 'Z'), \
    S
```

You can add the function to [`ISPPBuiltins.iss`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=builtinsiss) in Inno Setup installation folder.

---

If you need locale-aware uppercasing, you can invoke PowerShell from preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

The [`UpperCase`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=uppercase) support function was finally [added in Inno Setup 6.0.4](https://jrsoftware.github.io/issrc/whatsnew.htm) and functions similarly to [`LowerCase`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=lowercase):

> The conversion affects only 7-bit ASCII characters between 'A' and 'Z'.

If you need to uppercase strings with characters beyond the basic Latin alphabet, you'll have to turn to [`StringChange`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=stringchange) or an external call as [noted by Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48073808/3427178).